# Show a portion of a <div> instead of display: none for slide up text reveal

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideup, jquery-effects

I'm using CSS and JQuery to create a slide up text reveal on hover. My challenge is that I can only create this effect by using a `display: none;` property on the classes ". I'd prefer to have the heading (Admissions) in the `<div>` that's currently hidden to be visible at all times.

I've linked to a few jpg's that visually explain what I'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.img_frame').hover(function() {
    $('.caption', this).slideToggle('slow');
  }, function() {
    $('.caption', this).slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.img_frame .caption {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background-color: rgb(67, 121, 160);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.blue_box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 599px;
  background-color: rgb(67, 121, 160);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="admissions_link img_frame col span_4">
  <div class="blue_box caption">
    <h3>Admissions</h3>
    <p>We understand that parents often start this process with many questions about how to decide what is the best placement for their child. We encourage you to get to know Riverside School and learn how we have worked for over forty years in the Richmond
      community to serve the needs of students with dyslexia and other related language-based learning differences.</p>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <h2 class="learn_btn">LEARN MORE</h2>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Current Slide Up Effect:

[image]

Desired Slide Up Effect:

[image]

Comment: Your snippet doesn't really do... well, anything. Your question needs to have a [*verifiable* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just make a container `<div>` that holds both the "Admissions" text as one child `<div>` and the information you want to slide up as a second one. Then just call `slideDown` on the one with the additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change your HTML to

```
<div class="admissions_link img_frame col span_4">
  <div class="blue_box">
    <h3>Admissions</h3>
    <div class="caption"> <!-- new wrapper class -->
        <p>We understand that parents often start this process with many questions about how to decide what is the best placement for their child. We encourage you to get to know Riverside School and learn how we have worked for over forty years in the Richmond
  community to serve the needs of students with dyslexia and other related language-based learning differences.</p>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
          <h2 class="learn_btn">LEARN MORE</h2>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit for clarity:

I removed the class of caption from the wrapper `div.blue_box` and created a sub wrapper under the `h3` so when the javascript closes the `div.caption` it only closes what you want to have hidden.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've made the changes and edited one line of CSS (changed .blue_box height to 125px instead of 599px). This gets me closer to the effect I'm trying to achieve, however, the child <div class="caption> now slides up over the "Admissions" text. Any thoughts?

Comment: @sanzanobi Try taking off the `position: absolute` from your css pertaining to `.img_frame .caption`

Comment: Removing that positioning causes the hidden <div> to slide down instead of up.

Comment: Could you make a working example? As long as the `position: absolute` is still on the `.blue_box` it should be fine as.

Comment: Here's the url to the dev http://riversideschool.rpmdevserver.com/. Hover over the admissions tab on the right just below the header image.

Comment: Ah, I see, remove the height from `.blue_box`, then add `.blue_box {height: 125px;}` and `.img_frame .caption {height: 474px;}`

Comment: Thanks again for the help. The height of .blue_box is currently 125px so I'm a bit unclear on your direction.

Comment: My bad, add that height to `.blue_box h3`, so to correct my previouse statement, remove the height from `.blue_box`, then add `.blue_box h3 {height: 125px;}`